# How to notify that Array has particular DataPoint

Tags: c#, arrays

Alright so my problem here is I'm trying to create a user input array, and notify console if a specific data point is in the user input array. I realize you can  *see*  that the data point is there on the console, but I've been asked to do this and I don't ask why :'D.

```
public static void Main()
{

    double [] array= new double [10]
    double temp;

    Console.WriteLine("Insert 10 numbers");

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    Console.WriteLine("What number do you wish to find?");

    temp = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

    foreach (int i in array)
    {
        if (temp == i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The number is in the array.")
            break;
        }

        else if (temp != i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The number is not part of the array.");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The output is: if you put the number that was in the first slot, it would come out as "The number is in the array", any other number that is part of the array will out put "The number is not part of the array" . If you remove the breaks in the If and Else if codes, the list will tell you one by one if the number is or is not part of the array.

How do I make it that it reads the entire array, and tells me that whatever number is part of the array?

**Note**  I've been asked not to use LINQ nor the Array. objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not check for `temp != i`, but `==` only within the loop:

```
  // array is double[] - item is double
  foreach (double item in array) {
    // item found, we shall report and exit the method
    if (item == temp) { // <- dubious: we should check doubles with tolerance
      Console.WriteLine("The number is in the array.");

      return; // <- not break
    }
  }

  // entire array has been scanned, no item found
  Console.WriteLine("The number is not part of the array.");
```

If you don't want to `return`, but insist on `break`:

```
  bool inTheArray = false;

  foreach (double item in array)
    if (item == test) {
      inTheArray = true;

      break;
    }   

  Console.WriteLine(inTheArray 
    ? "The number is in the array." 
    : "The number is not part of the array.");
```